# What is the best practice to unlock an already-deferred read-unlock RWMutex before the end of the function?

Tags: go, mutex

I'm working on a database and I want to know the *best* way to solve this issue.

Basically, I would like to unlock the read mutex earlier in the function because the last bit is concurrent safe.

```golang
func (s *Structure) Get(key interface{}, object interface{}) (found bool, err error ){
    s.RLock()
    defer s.RUnlock()

    // Concurrent-dangerous stuff begins
    ref, err := s.Index.GetOneEquals(string(s.StructName), key)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }

    path := ref.ToPath(s.StructName)
    if (path == nil) {
        return false, nil
    }

    value, err := dbdrivers.DB.Get(path)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    // Concurrent-dangerous stuff ends
    // RUnlock should technically be here

    err = encoding.Marshaler.Unmarshal(value, object)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
}
```

If I just add an s.RUnlocked at the bottom part (where it says RUnlocked should technically be here) while keeping the deferred statement, if I understand correctly, it will cause issues. As I understand it, RUnlock works via a counter. So if my program reaches beyond that point ("RUnlocked should technically be here"), it will call the s.RUnlocked **and** also the deferred s.RUnlocked as well when the function ends. So the counter will decrement two times which might cause a disaster.

Therefore, the only solution I can think of is this - which is begging for gotchas down the line because I need to think of everywhere the function can end:

```golang
func (s *Structure) Get(key interface{}, object interface{}) (found bool, err error ){
    s.RLock()

    // Concurrent-dangerous stuff begins
    ref, err := s.Index.GetOneEquals(string(s.StructName), key)
    if err != nil {
        s.RUnlock() // <----
        return false, err
    }

    path := ref.ToPath(s.StructName)
    if (path == nil) {
        s.RUnlock() // <----
        return false, nil
    }

    value, err := dbdrivers.DB.Get(path)
    if err != nil {
        s.RUnlock() // <----
        return false, err
    }
    // Concurrent-dangerous stuff ends
    // RUnlock should technically be here
    s.RUnlock() // <----

    err = encoding.Marshaler.Unmarshal(value, object)
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
}
```

Is there a safer way to do this?

Comment: What's *best* is an opinion. Please edit your question to focus on *objective* metrics, or your question risks being closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `defer` if you put the inner block into its own function:

```
func (s *Structure) Get(key interface{}, object interface{}) (found bool, err error ){

    s.RLock()
    failed, found, err:= func() {
      defer s.RUnlock()
         ref, err := s.Index.GetOneEquals(string(s.StructName), key)
         if err != nil {
            return true, false, err
         }
         // Do stuff
         return false, found, nil
    }()
    if failed {
      return found, err
    }
    // continue function, lock is unlocked
}
```